# Why Am I Getting Undefined Reference Here?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, uefi

So I was following this
[GNU-EFI Tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/GNU-EFI)

But what I am actually trying to do is get [something more like this](https://wiki.osdev.org/GOP)

Where that code is essentially something I can call in the main code of my kernel.
Something like

```
void kernel_main(void) {
    initialize_gop();
}
```

Where `initialize_gop` looks like

```
void initialize_gop()
{
    EFI_GUID gopGuid = EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL_GUID;
    EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL *gop;

    int status = uefi_call_wrapper(BS->LocateProtocol, 3, &gopGuid, NULL, (void**)&gop);
    if(EFI_ERROR(status))
        printf("Unable to locate GOP");
}
```

The problem is when I try to link the `gop.so` file to the kernel binary I still get undefined reference:

```
ld: /SomePath/gnu-efi/ia32/gnuefi/crt0-efi-ia32.o: warning: relocation against `efi_main' in read-only section `.text'
ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a shared object
/SomePath/kernel/arch/i386/gop.so: undefined reference to `efi_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
i686-elf-gcc --sysroot=/SomePath/sysroot -isystem=/usr/include -I/SomePath/gnu-efi/inc -fpic -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-check -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -maccumulate-outgoing-args -c arch/i386/gop.c -o arch/i386/gop.o -Iinclude -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64
ld -shared -m elf_i386 -shared -Bsymbolic -L/SomePath/gnu-efi/ia32/lib -L/SomePath/gnu-efi/ia32/gnuefi -T/SomePath/gnu-efi/gnuefi/elf_ia32_efi.lds /SomePath/gnu-efi/ia32/gnuefi/crt0-efi-ia32.o arch/i386/gop.o -o arch/i386/gop.so -lgnuefi -lefi
i686-elf-gcc --sysroot=/SomePath/sysroot -isystem=/usr/include -T arch/i386/linker.ld  -o myos.kernel -O2 -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra  -I/SomePath/gnu-efi/inc   arch/i386/crti.o arch/i386/crtbegin.o arch/i386/boot.o arch/i386/tty.o  kernel/kernel.o   -nostdlib -lk -lgcc  arch/i386/crtend.o arch/i386/crtn.o  arch/i386/nasm_int32.o /SomePath/kernel/arch/i386/gop.so
```

Comment: the first link you provide shows that your entry point must be called efi_main, thats what the linker is looking for so why did you create kernel_main

Comment: I was wondering if I could avoid having that be the entry point. I want to be able to call the GOP api from my kernel

Comment: just change the name from kernel_main to efi_main

Comment: I'm actually illiterate thanks haha